# Student badge without upvote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1753857) user got the Student badge but has no up-voted question.

His reputation changes only show the changes to be due to accepting answers
(no reputation earned due to up-votes).
How is this possible?
Has he deleted the question with the up-vote?
If so, should still he have the Student badge?

The user has 5 rep as of 24-01-2013 and has accepted 2 answers (2+2 rep earned).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the [info for the badge for this user](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2/student?userid=1753857), you can see that the user had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941076/python-tkinter-listbox-os-walkdir-insert-into-listbox) up-voted which was subsequently deleted. Such badges are not removed.

Incidentally, the deleted question has a score of 0, still; because it was also down voted.

Comment: How did you come to know the vote-count of the question?

Comment: @paddila It's one of the privileges for [established users @ 1k](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user)

Comment: Even after it's deleted?

Comment: @paddila: 1) 10k+ users can see deleted questions, and 2) 1k+ users can see the vote count. Yes, even on deleted questions we can see the vote breakdown.

Answer (score 3):

General (i.e., non-tag) badges, once awarded, are not retracted again.

There are several ways the badge could have been awarded:

- Votes *can* be retracted (within a grace period or after the post has been edited).
- Questions can also be *downvoted* again.
- Questions can be deleted, even when upvoted (as long as there is no upvoted answer or more than one answer on it, or if closed).

The user must have received a vote for a question which was subsequently retracted, downvoted or deleted.

In this case, the badge was awarded for a [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941076/python-tkinter-listbox-os-walkdir-insert-into-listbox) (10k+ users only). It's a double whammy in this case; it was both downvoted *and* deleted. The badge was awarded on Oct. 17th, but the question was not deleted until the next day.

Comment: So, if a person no longer is eligible for a badge, shouldn't the badge be retracted?

Comment: @paddila: nope. Badges are forever. For some badges, the requirements are too transient in any case; the 'populist' badge is hard enough to earn; if you lost the badge because the accepted answer gained a few more upvotes most of the ones so far awarded would have to be retracted again. Then awarded again when your answer gains a few more upvotes...

Comment: @MartijnPieters - **tag** badges are revoked if you drop below the award criteria again.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63148/proposed-changes-to-tag-based-badges. I can cofirm for tex.sx that several tag badges were taken away when the criteria not applied anymore (either because of retagging questions or of nullifyig upvotes).

Comment: @ChrisF: Yup, confirmed that on the [Badges FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854), thanks.