# Tag badge IDs don't seem to make a lot of sense

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-badges

Here's an example of a bronze badge:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/86/status-completed

Here's an example of a silver badge:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/47/status-completed

Why does the 400 upvote badge have an ID of 47 when the 100 upvote one has an ID of 86? I assume the IDs are created when someone is first awarded a badge. So someone got 400 upvotes before they got 100 upvotes?

Comment: Why would these numbers have to make any sort of sense? They're just ids.

Comment: I just would have expected them to be created sequentially but, as noted in my post, that does not appear to be the case. User IDs are usually sequential on most systems as are post IDs. Doesn't seem unreasonable to assume that tag badge IDs would be as well.

Comment: Sure. I'm don't really understand what you expect of this question though. Why does this matter? (Also note that tag badges can disappear. Could simply be reuse of freed slots.)

Comment: You're around the SQL tags enough @mat to know it's unlikely to be reuse of IDs...

Comment: @Mat - just curiosity. I don't imagine most questions here really "matter". Why does it matter what the tag badge thresholds are? For that matter, why do badges "matter"? And yet despite that http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work got upvoted quite a bit.

Comment: @neubert: that matters a damn bit more than what the internal id of a tag badge is! I care about having gotten Generalist - was great fun trying to get it actually. I didn't know until now and couldn't care less that it's id is 15 on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want your mind blown, [Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) was [awarded the bronze](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=activity&sort=badges&page=82) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag badge *before it even existed*. "How could this be?" you may ask. [Stay a while and listen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAVVy_x3Erg&feature=player_detailpage#t=1s) to my tale...

In the before-times, there were only [silver and gold tag badges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/specialist-badge-implemented/) – Bronze tag badges were [only added later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63148/proposed-changes-to-tag-based-badges), and, since various silver/gold tag badges had already been awarded at that point, they presumably ended up with higher ID values than their more elusive counterparts.

Comment: Mind blowing indeed!